# Last item of list is overwriting

Tags: c#, image, list, overwrite

I'm stuck with something I can't figure it out.

I add the bitmap to it when the mouse is down

```
List<Image> ChangeHistory = new List<Image>();
int ChangeHistoryIndex = 0;

private void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ChangeHistoryIndex = ChangeHistory.Count - 1;

    if (canvas.Image != null)
    {
        ChangeHistory.Add(canvas.Image);
    }

    MouseIsDown = true;
}
```

This is the Undo button event, if that's clicked all items in ChangeHistory are the same.

```
private void Undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeHistoryIndex--;

    if(ChangeHistoryIndex != 0) 
    {
        canvas.Image = ChangeHistory[ChangeHistoryIndex];
    }
}
```

I really can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: You should change ChangeHistoryIndex after adding the image on MouseDown.

Comment: Side note: Undo stack should be implemented with deep cloning or action replay. Adding reference to live object with `List.Add` not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your index after using the list.

```
private void Undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if(ChangeHistoryIndex != -1) 
    {
        canvas.Image = ChangeHistory[ChangeHistoryIndex];
    }
    ChangeHistoryIndex--;
}
```

Edit: You should also assign the ChangeHistoryIndex in the other method:

```
private void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (canvas.Image != null)
   {
       ChangeHistory.Add(canvas.Image);
   }
   ChangeHistoryIndex = ChangeHistory.Count - 1;
   MouseIsDown = true;
}
```

---

Edit: You are implementing a stack structure. so you can use Stack instead of List:

```
Stack<Image> ChangeHistory = new Stack<Image>();
```

and use it with `Push` and `Pop` methods in your events like this:

```
    private void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (canvas.Image != null)
            ChangeHistory.Push(canvas.Image);
        MouseIsDown = true;
    }

    private void Undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChangeHistory.Count > 0)
            canvas.Image = ChangeHistory.Pop();
        else
            canvas.Image = null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not going to help.

Comment: You should also assign the ChangeHistoryIndex in the other method.

Comment: have you had any success?